# make:entity command creates attribute of type relation with _id suffix

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Always when I create entity attribute of type "relation", the column in database is named like this:

```
name_id
```

I want it to not create the `_id` suffix. I think it is maybe because it doesn't specify name and referencedColumn in the `@JoinColumn‘ annotation by default.

When I specify it by hand and rename the column in database, it works without the `_id` suffix.

Is it possible to override this behavior or I'll have to rewrite it everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you are not saving the object in the database but the id of the object to the database so the _id makes sense or at least to me it does.

If you still wish to do this, after creating the entity change the annotations to reflect the name change and specify the joinColumn in the annotation before running the make:migration command so then you don't need to edit the database.

Alternatively you will have to fork the Maker bundle and then you can change the default setup to however you like.